# Accessing signal of privately inherited ancestor

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I have created class B (a descendant of QObject), whose public & protected methods should be visible to descendants of B but not to any classes outside of those descendants.  So descendant class D inherits from B as private:

```
class B : public QObject {}
class D: private B {}
```

However, in D I need to connect to signals emitted from B.  The only way I can *connect* to those signals is to inherit B as public.  Otherwise I get a compiler error that

> QObject is an inaccessible base of D

Does that mean D must inherit from B as public, and I must create private methods in D to override every public method in B?  and somehow hide enums, etc. (Seems like a lot of work, there must be a better way)

I am using Qt 5, and I thought in Qt 5 onwards signals are public.  Or is the connect method hidden?  Note that B contains some virtual methods that need to be overridden by D, so I cannot just make B an member of D.

Comment: Why inherit privately from B instead of aggregating a B as a member?

Comment: I still have to override some methods of B for my implementation but otherwise that would work. But for sake of learning, shouldn't D be able to connect to signals of B?

Comment: Show how you make a connection.

Comment: ixSci: pretty straight forward connect, but if it helps: connect(this,&d::mysig,this,&D::myslot,Qt::QueuedConnection);